# Elapsed time in client does not work TCP SOCKET

Tags: c, tcp, timer

Client side works like this

```
clock_t s, f;

while(TRUE){
    write
    s_time = clock()

    read    
    f_time = clock();

    double client_time = (double)(f_time - s_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    fprintf(stderr, "ct = %lf\n", client_time);
}
```

Right after I send a message to the server, the timer starts and when the client reads a message from the server, the timer stops. In server it takes 5 to 10 seconds to answer back to clien. Here is my problem. the timer in client shows only a very short of time elapsed. around only 0.0000085. How do I keep the real elapsed time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clock` measures CPU time, that is how much time the CPU spent executing the code. Your code however is mostly *not* utilizing CPU: it is blocked (in other words, doing nothing) while `read` was waiting for data to arrive.

To measure the wall time elapsed, use `gettimeofday` instead of `clock`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know clock measured only cpu time